# In what order are events handled if two event handlers exist for the same element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got an MVC .cshtml page with an event handler for my button in the javascript:

```
$('#myButton').on('click', function () {
    //Do stuff
});
```

However, in the javascript file on the page, myPage.js, the event handler has also been created:

```
$('#myButton').on('click', function () {
    //Do stuff in the .js file
});
```

I understand that both of these events will be called should myButton be clicked. However, I don't know what order this will happen in. Both of the event handlers reference the same ID, rather than separate elements (I've seen threads where users have asked about window.click compared to button.click but this has the exact same event).

As far as I can see, the code in the .js file appears to be running first. But I can't understand why this would happen.

Is there any logic behind this, or is it pure coincidence?

Answer (score 4):

Event handlers are typically handled in the order they were added. You can easily test this:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  console.log('first');
});

$('button').on('click', function() {
  console.log('second');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click me</button>
```

Internally, event listeners are stored as an array on each element. When an event is triggered, the array is iterated over and each listener is called in order. This is how most "PubSub" systems work.

Here's some pseudo-code to explain the basics of how events work.

```
listeners = []

addEventListener(name, handler):
    listeners += {name, handler}

trigger(name):
    for listener in listeners:
        if listener.name == name:
            call(handler)
```

Comment: Nice answer. I always assumed that they would run asynchronously.

Comment: No, that isn't possible. Javascript is single threaded. Besides, you'd still have to keep track of all the listeners somewhere so you'd most likely end up with a list that gets triggered in order anyways.